# Proper Flag position over histogram bell curve

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using histogram bell curve for a project, everything is working fine except flag position like given in picture.[image]

Here is link of my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8q1t3mwb/4

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Bell curve'
    },

    xAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' }
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Bell curve' },
        opposite: true
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' }
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Bell curve' },
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Bell curve',
        type: 'bellcurve',
        id:'dataseries',
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: 1,
        zIndex: -1,
        color: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 1,
                y2: 0
            },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
            ]
        }
    }]
});
```

See full code here, https://jsfiddle.net/8q1t3mwb/4

Comment: Where do you expect them to be?

Comment: anywhere on the edge of curve,like shown in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the points where they currently are because your flags are on the scatter axis. If you turn on the scatter points, you will see that.

Therefore, if you set the following for the flag series:

```
{
  yAxis: 1,
  xAxis: 1,
  name: 'Pointer',
  type: 'flags',
  ...
}
```

And adjust your `x` value according to the number on the bell curve you will be able to see the flag connected to the curve.

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/8q1t3mwb/6/